# Mexican Wife in UK Registering to Vote for Mex Election July 2018

Tags: united-kingdom, mexico, elections

my wife is Mexican and lives with me in the UK on a Spousal Visa. She has not lived in the UK long (under 4 years) but would like to vote in the 2018 election in July this year.

Can anyone tell me what is the process for her registering to vote from the UK, if it is at all possible?

Comment: One might think that the Mexican embassy in London might have some clues.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in [a comment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/mexican-wife-in-uk-registering-to-vote-for-mex-election-july-2018#comment23706_13938) by [audionuma](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/2144/audionuma), the [Mexican Embassy in London](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/en/) does indeed have [information about this](http://www.votoextranjero.mx/).

The page for voters residing abroad does not appear to have a version in English, but judging from the items under "¿CÓMO VOTAR?" ("how to vote?"), the process comprises four steps.  The relevant items are:

- ¿Cómo registrarse? (how to register)
- Recibe tu paquete (receive your packet)
- Marca tu Boleta (mark your ballot)
- Envía tu voto (send your vote)

Comment: *El periodo para tramitar tu credencial y votar con ella desde el extranjero en las Elecciones de 2018, concluyó el 31 de marzo.

Sin embargo, el trámite continúa en embajadas y consulados de manera permanente, para que puedas contar con una identificación oficial.* As I don't speak spanish, I don't wether it means _it's too late_ or not.